# Get the data of a filtered datasource

Tags: datasource, kendo-ui

I'm applying a filter on a datasource and I want to retrieve all the filtered data from this datasource.

The filter is correctly apply, my DropDownList is displaying only the filtered item, but when I want to get the data with Javascript, i'm retreiving every data and not only the filtered one.

Here is some code :

```
dropdownProduct.dataSource.query({ filter: filter }); 

var data = dropdownProduct.dataSource.data();
```

In the data variable I have all the data. Like I said, the query is working because my dropdown is only displaying the filtered data.

What can I do to only have the filtered data in the data variable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because the filtering is applied on the client side - and the **data** method returns all the data. You need to use the **[view](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#view)** method to retrieve only the visible to the end user data.

Comment: ok...my situation is, I have a kendo window which loads a grid with some data, now I'm applying filtering & then want to get that filtered data to my original view & enumarete through them one by one with the down arrow press event, I can do the rest but just need to find a way to get the filtered data. Can you help me please?